# In the Forgotten Realms, how did elven populations feed themselves?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, forgotten-realms

I’m building a world for a future campaign, it will feature elven civilizations. In order to place and design cities, I wish to know how FR handled food in elven populations.

1. **What do elves eat?** Are they vegetarians, meat eaters, or a mix of both?
2. **Did elves practice farming?** Are there stories of elves cultivating fields, planting crops, etc.?
3. **Did elves raise livestock?**
4. **Do elves eat as much as humans?**

To be more clear, I’m specifically interested in examples from sources canon to the Forgotten Realms, or from rule books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete elves handbook has several paragraphs dealing with Elven diet.  It came out with 2nd edition

In a nutshell anything a Human can eat an Elf can eat however their prefer delicate foods and eat less then Humans. Elfs do not eat as much

They are vegetarians in part due to heavier foods like beef can cause stomach distress, they eat meat but only in small amounts. Any meat pretty much comes from they cull the excess animal population

Elves love wine and they have some kind of wine that has nectar from flowers mixed with honey in it.
Elfs can survive on the fruits of the forest, livestock and farming are unnecessary and boring

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I’ll try to look into those paragraphs. Nonetheless, I doubt that foraging can sustain entire cities with tens of thousands. So with famous examples of settlements like Evermeet or Myth Drannor, I always wondered how they handled food.